# Visual Studio compiler is so much slower than MinGW

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw, iostream

Hi I tried to see how much c++ will take to count 1 to 100000 I tried with Visual Studio and it took **12.9604** seconds to run even python will run faster I tried using printf similar result then I tried using MinGW compiler and it took **0.0095653** in MinGW compiler to run  I used the same code for both then I tried removing std::cout from the loop and they both took about 3 seconds and not much difference.
can anyone tell me why?
here is my code:

```
#include <chrono> // for std::chrono::high_resolution_clock
#include <iostream> // for std::cout

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); // get the time before start
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); // get the time after it's finished
    std::chrono::duration<double> took = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(end - start); // calculates how much it took to run
    std::cout << "It took " << took.count() << " seconds to run the program";
}
```

**Edit:** this was not a good benchmark MinGW IDE used its own console which was faster than Visual studio which uses cmd I tried to use cmd for the MinGW application too and the results were similar.

Comment: Did you compile in debug or release mode?

Comment: Do you use same console?

Comment: Nitpicking: It's not the _Visual Studio compiler_ which runs your program... (Once, the C++ program is compiled it's a more or less self-standing executable.)

Comment: Microbenchmarks can vary widely and in this specific case you are testing int-to-string and buffer size used by standard streams. Add to this all possible kinds of differences between mentioned toolchains (especially compiler/linker/build options) and you are set up for hundreds of possibilities.

Comment: Your code is not benchmarking the compiler output at all. It is benchmarking the `cout` mechanism and the OS's way of rendering said output to a terminal. Try redirecting output to a file and the difference should be much much smaller.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried both but the same result I usually use CTRL + F5 to run without debugging

Comment: No, you need to explicitly build in "Release" mode. That is the mode where the compiler actually optimizes. Debug is dog slow.

Comment: @Botje This isn't really something that's significantly addressed by building in Debug vs Release, the Windows console will still take a long time to display the text. Replacing the `std::cout << i << '\n';` with writing to a file will have performance much more comparable to the linux-y version.

Comment: @Jarod42 no Visual Studio runs in it cmd but VS Code (With MinGW) runs it in its own console I tried running it in cmd and it was as low as Visual Studio Compiler